# Eclipselink JPA onetomany relationship

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I am trying to model a simple OneToMany relationship with EclipseLink JPA & MySQL. It fails with some error messages. Can anyone help me to understand what it is missing ?

```
@Entity
public class Job implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long jobId;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity=Applicant.class,mappedBy="job",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Applicant> applicant;

    //Gettters and Setters
}

@Entity
public class Applicant {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long applicantId;


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="job_Id")
    private Job job;


    //Gettters and Setters
}
```

TestCode

```
Job job=new Job ();
List <Applicant> applicants=new ArrayList<Applicant>();
Applicant applicant=new Applicant();
applicants.add(applicant);
job.setApplicant(applicants);
em.persist(job);// EntityManager Reff
```

Error message:

```
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'job_Id' in 'field list'
```

Comment: Do you have `job_Id` column in table `Applicant`?

Comment: I heard its not required and we can give any name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a foreign key column in your `Applicant` table.

You've annotated relation to `Job` with `@JoinColumn(name="job_Id")`. `@JoinColumn` is not necessary, because JPA is all about convention over configuration, which means there are default values which are implied if you don't override them. Without this annotation, EclipseLink would search for column named `job_jobId` (`<field name>_<id column name in target table>`). Since you stated that join column is `job_Id`, you need to have that column in `Applicant` table.

These are the database tables that should go with your entity mappings (with `@JoinColumn(name = "job_Id")`):

```
TABLE JOB
    JOBID (PRIMARY KEY)

TABLE APPLICANT
    APPLICANTID (PRIMARY KEY)
    JOB_ID (FOREIGN KEY TO JOB#JOBID)
```

Comment: I removed the @JoinColumn.Here is a new error message : Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mydb`.`applicant`, CONSTRAINT `FK_APPLICANT_APPLICANTID` FOREIGN KEY (`APPLICANTID`) REFERENCES `job` (`JOBID`))

Comment: Generated SQLs: INSERT INTO JOB (JOBID) VALUES (?)
bind => [2401]

INSERT INTO APPLICANT (APPLICANTID, JOB_JOBID) VALUES (?, ?)
bind => [2402, null]

Comment: Why does JOB_JOBID is not populated in second insert?

Comment: You need to add `applicant.setJob(job)` to your code.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Entity
public class Job implements Serializable{

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        @Column(name="job_id")
        private long jobId;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy="job",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
        private List<Applicant> applicants;

        public Job(){
            applicants = new ArrayList<Applicant>();
        }

        public List<Applicant> getApplicants(){
            //force clients through addApplicant() method to encapsulate setting both sides of relationship
            return Collections.unmodifiableList(applicants);
        }

        public void addApplicant(Applicant applicant){
            //set both sides of relationship
            applicant.setJob(this);
            applicants.add(applicant);
        }
    }

    @Entity
    public class Applicant {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private long applicantId;


        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="job_Id")
        private Job job;
    }   


    Job job = new Job ();
    Applicant applicant = new Applicant();
    job.addApplicant(applicant);
    em.persist(job);
```